# Circular cut out in rectangle using Android drawables

Tags: android, shapes

I would like to create the same shape as depicted in [Transparent half circle cut out of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503636/transparent-half-circle-cut-out-of-a-div) using Android drawables and fill the created circle with a round button, is creating this shape (not the round button) possible? Preferably with drawables and xml only, but I guess using paint and canvas is fine too.

So far I was thinking to use the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121617/creating-transparent-circle-cutout-in-a-view-in-android) to create a transparent circle at the desired position:

```
Paint mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFF);
mPaint.setAlpha(0);
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
        PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

But can this be done non-programatically?

Comment: no, you cannot use xml for this, whats the problem in doing that in java?

Comment: try using vector drawable

Answer (score 0):

1) Create drawable oval with white color in xml.

2) Create a Relative layout with black background.

3) Draw the image with background of oval drawable over relative Layout.

Comment: That would work. But in my case I would like to use a semi-transparent background. If the background is opaque then you will see a color difference.

Comment: I guess I will make a custom view that extends e.g. a relativelayout. Will update if I succeed.